# Example of wicket atmosphere with channel

Tags: java, wicket

> I just saw new features released at wicket 6.40. And I am interested
>   to see example code of the atmosphere channel. Where can i find the
>   example of this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quickstart application of integrating Wicket and Atmosphere.

https://github.com/papegaaij/wicket-atmosphere-quickstart

- `atmosphere.xml` can be found under `src/main/webapp/META-INF/`
- `web.xml` under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a minimal example:
http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/atmosphere/?0

It is similar to [*RJo*'s link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889178/199048). In addition:

- There is an online demo.
- Custom objects are pushed to the `EventBus`, so You'll see that everything might be transfered as long as it is `Serializable`.

Summary:

- An `EventBus` instance is initialized in `AtmosphereApplication.java`.
- This `EventBus` is used in `HomePage.java` to push messages.
- `@Subscribe` annotations in `HomePage.java` are used to receive messages.

Comment: +1 for the summary. I originally posted the same link, but apparently, the online demo is not working and there is no `atmosphere.xml` to be found. Furthermore, the sources are not working but can be found at https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/atmosphere

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found a link to the example source by an internet search, I was able to browse all the sources, but with the link I've posted I get an internal error. So your example is better.