# Configuration + Code example of using Atmosphere with Wicket?

Tags: wicket, atmosphere

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984687/example-of-wicket-atmosphere-with-channel) has an answer which points to a non-working example and the 
[conversation on the mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/users-wicket.apache.org/2012-06/msg00248.html) is very vague. Is there any working example of using Wicket 6.5.0 with Atmosphere?

Or is there any other viable server-push technology that integrates with wicket?

Specifically i am looking for a complete web.xml (atmosphere.xml if needed), Application and Page classes

Answer (score 0):

The github project RJo is linking to works fine for me.
[wicket-atmosphere-quickstart](https://github.com/papegaaij/wicket-atmosphere-quickstart)

I used the embedded jetty server to run it and went to `http://localhost:8080/app/`